# Inputs alignment inside container

Tags: php, html, css

I have such an issue:
There are two inputs in the container: the text field and the submit button. The problem is that when the text is changed by the locale (For example from English to French), the button gets stratched and overlaps the text field. Here are the examples:

English:
[image: English]

French:
[image: French]

Is there any way, so the length of the search field will fit the container automatically?

The code for this container is like that:

```
  <div id="searchContainer">
    <input type="text" id="searchField" class="search" name="searchQ" />
    <?php echo $this->searchButton; ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Make the width of the text field like `width="70%"` or something like that.. hope it helps..

Comment: The problem is that the button width is dynamic, I've already tried the percentage in width - if it helps in one point, so there is a big space in the other. :(

Comment: maybe add some z-index for your button...

Comment: Decrease your search button font size...

Comment: Thn you need to make the `searchContainer` to have dynamic width, and put some margin between the inputfield and the button...

Comment: @Akhil that is not a good decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the help of jQuery then the following code can solve your problem.

html code-

```
<div id="form" class="loading">
        <form action="">
            <div id="container">
                <input type="text" name="input" id="input" value="">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="s">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

css and js-

```
    <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var containerWidth = $("#form #container").outerWidth();
                var searchBoxWidth = jQuery("#form #s").outerWidth();               
                var adjustedWidth = containerWidth -  searchBoxWidth - 30   //  this is a value i've chosen to separate the button from the input field and the right edge of the wrapper
                jQuery("#form #input").width(adjustedWidth);
jQuery("#form").removeClass('loading');
            });
        </script>

        <style>
.loading form{visibility:hidden;background:url(img/loader.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%}
/*url should follow your own link to the gif you want to use*/
            #form{width:700px;margin:200px auto;}
            #form #container{border-radius: 30px;height: 60px;background: #ccc;border: 0;padding:0}
            #form #input{height: 40px;margin: 10px 0 0 10px;border-radius: 30px;border: 0;padding:0;}
            #form #s{padding: 13px 28px;border: 0;border-radius: 30px;text-transform: uppercase;}
        </style>
```

edit:

1. I've added a class "loading" in the main wrapper to identify the loading stage. Initial I don't want any visitor see the contents inside the wrapper so that i set the rule `visibility:hidden` so that the contents will remain in the position and they are not displayed instead i'm showing a loading gif using the `background` property of the `loader` class.
2. when the width of the input box is set then i'm removing the class `loading` from the wrapper so that the contents are now visible.

Comment: I've just made the way you wrote. :) Thanks.

Comment: Well, the proble is that you cannot set that width before rendering, so the width "jumps" in front of the user's eyes. 'window.onload' doesn't help :(

Comment: well, this is because the js will start working right after everything in the dom are loaded (images are not in the dom). If it takes some time to load the dom then visitors will see the jump. If you don't want the jump then either you may use a table based layout which is not semantic and always discouraged to use or you can set a small loading graphic which will be removed after the content has loaded. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*I had a similar issue when styling a multi-lingual form myself, and while I never found an optimal solution, I'll share what I ended up doing in case it helps.*

Unfortunately, styling dynamic forms is rarely easy and sometimes impossible. You can, however, style the input field based on the language of the page. First make sure the page html reflects the language you are using (i generate this based on language using server side code, in your case it should be a straight forward php echo statement):

```
<body lang="en">
```

Next, select your text input based on the language

```
#searchField {
    width: 80%; /* default width */
}
body[lang|="en"] #searchField {
    width: 70%; /* make space for english button */
}
```

There are multiple other ways of selecting depending on language, check out http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having tables for layout you can do it like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NJmwB/)):

```
<style>
.search-table {
    width:100%;
}
.search-table .search{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
}
.search-table .btn-cell {
    width:1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
</style>
<div id="searchContainer">
    <table class="search-table">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="searchField" class="search" name="searchQ" /></td>
            <td class="btn-cell"><button>search</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```